# Construct a parallel to a line from a point outside the line in three euclidean moves

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to figure this out. It's one exercise of a set of 20, but this is the only one giving me problems.

The teacher of the course mentioned that it has to be done with two circumferences (the third move is the parallel line itself). So far I know that the two centers cannot be both on the given line or one in the point and the other in the line (none of the intersections give a parallel that way).

Solutions commonly found in the internet don't work since they go way over the three movement limit. The closest one I found required three circumferences (and therefore 4 moves).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Some questions: What is a line? (Straight?) What is a circumference? (Constructing a circle with given center and radius?) What are the Euclidean moves? (Connecting two points with a straight line, constructing a circle, constructing the intersections of circles and or straights?)

Comment: By line I meant straight line and by straight line and circle I meant the euclidean definitions of those, which I'm not sure how to translate properly but they can be found here: [link]http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/bookI.html defs 4 and 15. Also Euclidean moves are connecting two points with a straight line and constructing a circle. Marking a point does not use a movement.